# Hide columns in SSRS drill-down Report

Tags: report, ssrs-tablix, drilldown

I'm working on a multi-level drill down report for the last 2 days. How can i hide the remaining columns of the report on collapsing a particular group.

To be specific, My requirement is to initially display the first column, and on expanding, it should display second column and so on.

Any suggestions? How to achieve this in SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

Select the column and choose column visibility, then set the visibility property to hide and check the "Display can be toggled by this report item" and in drop down,select the first column textbox id and do the same for the columns which you want to hide.